# Fail to find enchant module in Windows

Tags: python, pyenchant

I'm trying to use Enchant module on Windows.
I installed the [PyEnchant exe](http://pyenchant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/download.html), and verified it is installed in `C:\Users\User\.windows-build-tools\python27\Lib\site-packages\enchant`

However when I try `import enchant` I get `ImportError: No module named enchant`.

What's going on?

Content of the above folder:

```
checker
errors.py
errors.pyc
errors.pyo
iconv.dll
intl.dll
lib
libenchant-1.dll
libglib-2.0-0.dll
libgmodule-2.0-0.dll
pypwl.py
pypwl.pyc
pypwl.pyo
share
tests.py
tests.pyc
tests.pyo
tokenize
utils.py
utils.pyc
utils.pyo
_enchant.py
_enchant.pyc
_enchant.pyo
__init__.py
__init__.pyc
__init__.pyo
```